# Custom TS typings not being recognized by compiler

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a typings file at `src/@types/yargs-interactive/index.d.ts` that I created for https://github.com/nanovazquez/yargs-interactive.  It's contents are as follows:

```
declare function yargsInteractive(): any;

declare namespace yargsInteractive {
  interface OptionData {
    type: string;
    describe: string;
    default?: string | number | boolean;
    prompt?: string;
  }

  interface Option {
    [key: string]: OptionData;
  }

  interface Interactive {
    usage(usage: string): any;
    interactive(options: Option[]): any;
    then(callback: (result: any) => any): any;
  }
}

export = yargsInteractive;
```

However when I try importing it, all I get is a `Could not find a declaration file for module 'yargs-interactive'` error.  I've tried changing my tsconfig.json file to add `typeRoots` to the `src/@types` directory, but it still doesn't find it. It recognizes it when it's under `node_modules/@types/yargs-interactive/index.d.ts`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it's not clear what is `that directory` that you are adding to `typeRoots` - is it `src/@types`?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's src/@types.  I reworded the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue comment,](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13581#issuecomment-273923793) `typeRoots` was meant for using globally-available types, not those that should be imported. Try using a [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) instead:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // baseUrl is required for paths to work
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/@types/*"]
    },
    // other options...
```